# PLease tell me how to auto click in popup window by using Id of popup window page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script> function autoClick(){var aut=window.open('https://www.mysite.com/mypage')document.getElementById('ID in abovepage').click();}</script><button onclick="autoclick()">Click me</button>
```

I want here when click on button popup window open and then in this opened window auto click on id in that page.Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just use variable created when window is opened.

```
var aut=window.open('https://www.mysite.com/mypage');
aut.document.getElementById('ID in abovepage').click(); // this will locate and click element within "aut" window.
```

Note: This will work only if parent and popup belong to the same domain.

Comment: And for diffrent parent and popup window what i can use please tell me

Comment: This approach is not available between different domains for security reason. But if you have control over both sites you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage technique to safely pass command to the popup to interpret.